# programatically nested fragments do not mirror parents lifecycle on navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-navigation

hoping someone can help me here,

I have two very simple fragments setup as destinations of a NavHostFragment and I am moving between them using navigate as follows:

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2)`

Fragment one is a dynamically adding a fragment to itself using the following:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            var fragment = SubFragment()
            val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            val ft = fm
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

When I click to navigate from Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 i can see that Fragment 1 goes through onPaused, onStop and onDestoryView as expected. But i don't get the matching calls for the sub fragment. Whereas if i switch the Sub Fragment to be added statically through XML it mirrors the lifecycle calls on removal. Do i need to manually trigger the lifecyle for dynamic fragments and if so how?

Fragment 1 layout

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragOneHead"
        android:text="Fragment One"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragOneHead"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

so my mistake is that I was using

```
 val fm = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
```

which would give the fragment the same lifecycle as the activity and not fragment 1, as i understand it. The correct method is:

```
val fm = childFragmentManager
```

Hope this helps someone else